How to re-enable Windows 10's acrylic blur effect after it disappeared?
I'm using Windows 10 Pro, version 22H2 (Build 19045.5011), and I've noticed that the acrylic blur effect has vanished from my taskbar and Start menu. This effect was previously active, and I'm looking for a way to restore it without performing a full in-place upgrade or system restore.
Here's what I've tried so far:

Appearance settings: Enabled Transparency Effects in Settings > Personalization > Colors, aswell as in Accessibility settings.

System file repairs: Ran sfc /scannow and DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth to repair system files, but neither restored the blur effect.

Registry tweaks:

Set UseOLEDTaskbarTransparency to 1 in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced.
Updated VisualFXSetting to 1 in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\VisualEffects.
Changed ForceEffectMode to 1 in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Dwm.
Modified both EnableBlurBehind and EnableTransparency to 1 or 0 in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Themes\Personalize. EnableBlurBehind seems to have no effect, while EnableTransparency controls taskbar transparency, but the Start menu remains opaque.


Past customizations: Previously used tools like Open-Shell, TaskbarX, OldNewExplorerCfg, and O&O ShutUp10. These have been uninstalled with no visible remnants, but I suspect they might have altered critical DLLs or system components, particularly those related to the Desktop Window Manager (DWM).


Since an in-place upgrade is too risky for my customized setup, I'm considering manually replacing specific system files, especially any DWM-related DLLs.
I saw someone with a similar issue here:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/m2in1a/acrylic_glassblur_effect_missing_since_kb4601319/
Any guidance on restoring the acrylic blur effect or advice on recovering essential files without a complete reinstallation would be greatly appreciated!
EDIT: Rolling the driver version back to 560.94 did not help.
Another interesting fact is, that open-shell (which I installed afterwards, to see if at least this is working) seems to update the glass effect only once, on checking the checkbox, which cannot be right (see GIF attached).


I have done dozens of in-place upgrades to the same version in recent years on my system, as a result I have not reinstalled Windows in over a decade, as long as you choose the option to “keep everything” everything will be migrated. However, I would also be cautious, if I had used some of those very invasive apps like O&O ShutUp10. Based on my research those applications are very invasive in the changes they make to your system.

The settings in Open Shell Menu allow for that blur effect, and persist even through Windows updates.

@DrMoishePippik I have used Open-Shell and I am sure the effect was working in the beginning, but for me it doesnt contiuosly update the acrylic effect which leads to visual artifacts that are rather unpleasant.

This is an issue with the latest Nvidia drivers (v566.03) that cause this issue.
In order to resolve this.

Use DDU to completely uninstall the current Nvidia Display Driver
Install a previous driver version from Nvidia website.

I tested with:
Driver Version - 561.09
Release Date - Tue Sep 17, 2024

Install that driver and select "Clean install" option from within the Nvidia driver installer
Reboot your PC
Make sure Transparency effect is turned on in Windows settings.

It should work after that.
Source: https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/game-ready-drivers/13/551473/geforce-grd-56603-feedback-thread-released-102224/

Windows 10 transparency effects not working correctly after updating to GRD 566.03 [4922638]


thank you for your answer! I will see what the implications of a downgrade are and decide if it's feasible to me.
Usually not, because modern software often requires up-to-date/the most recent drivers.
If it's too old, I'd not consider this an option.
Anyways, if it's only a temporary "bug", known to nvidia and microsoft, and they would fix it, then I'd just wait for this to happen.
If they think they get away with breaking what I paid money for, they are wrong and I'll never buy any product off them again.

sorry it took me a few days now to get back to this.
I am indeed on driver version 566.03 currently. I just saw there's an update to 566.14, which I'll try in a moment and see if it'll re-enable acrylic or not.
By the way: are you using GameReady or Studio drivers?
Thanks!

I have uninstalled my current driver by booting into Secure Mode and using DDU.
After a while my screen blacked out and when it got back up, it seems Microsoft installed 560.94 onto my system without asking.
Anyways, I cannot confirm that the acrylic blur effect works in this version either :/

@Manticore It's broken even in 566.14 - https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/forums/game-ready-drivers/13/552265/geforce-grd-56614-feedback-thread-released-111224/ ( They specfically mentioned this as an open issue ). I am using Game ready drivers. You can try to uninstall the drivers without a reboot and then install 561.09 or older then do a reboot.

This is super-frustrating atm, as now my taskbar completely disappears below the screen display. Well, except for the top line (1px) that is still visible.
It happened when I ticked the checkbox for transparency in the color settings.
At this point, I am really fed up with Windows. I would never in my life upgrade once more. This is the final straw for me. What a messed up piece of garbage this OS is is unbelievable.

Currently it seems the latest version of the driver that doesn't cause these problems is 565.90
